# Conditional counters on R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I got this dataset of firms, I have "completed the panel" so whenever the quantitative variables (Sales, wages) are 0 the firm is closed. The NA represents that I have completed the panel, that means all the firms have the same years, but NA is that the firm doesn't existed before (or after)

I want to make a counter for the first closure of the firm by each criteria.

So my data looks like this:

```
Year    Firm    sales   wages
2014    A        12      4   
2015    A        8       3
2016    A        0       0 
2017    A        NA      NA 
2018    A        NA      NA 

2014    B        NA      NA   
2015    B        8       3
2016    B        4       2 
2017    B        9       5 
2018    B        8       6 

2014    C        9       5   
2015    C        7       6
2016    C        0       0 
2017    C        0       0
2018    C        0       0

2014    D        9       5   
2015    D        7       6
2016    D        8       0 
2017    D        0       4
2018    D        NA      NA
```

And the desired result looks like this:

```
Year    Firm    sales   wages  Closure sales  Closure Wages    Closure (both)
2014    A        12      4        0                0                0
2015    A        8       3        0                0                0
2016    A        0       0        1                1                1    # Firm closed here
2017    A        NA      NA       2                2                2    # Doesn't appear on the original df but it's closed
2018    A        NA      NA       3                3                3    # Same here

2014    B        NA      NA       0                0                0    # Firm has not opened yet
2015    B        NA      NA       0                0                0    #Same here
2016    B        4       2        0                0                0
2017    B        9       5        0                0                0
2018    B        8       6        0                0                0

2014    C        9       5        0                0                0  
2015    C        7       6        0                0                0
2016    C        0       0        1                1                1   #Firm closed but still have obligations, so it appears 
2017    C        0       0        2                2                2  # Same
2018    C        0       0        3                3                3  # Same

2014    D        9       5        0                0                0 
2015    D        7       6        0                0                0
2016    D        8       0        0                1                1 #Firm closed by wages criteria, but somehow still sells
2017    D        0       4        1                2                2 #Firm doesn't sell anything, but pays wages.
2018    D        NA      NA       2                3                3  #Firm doesn't have any obligations left.
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why all closure sales and Closure Wages is 0 for Firm = B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a messy bit of logic.  The only way I know how to do it is with a [datastep](https://libr.r-sassy.org/reference/datastep.html) from the [libr](https://libr.r-sassy.org/) package.  The `datastep` allows you to walk through the dataframe and nest the  conditionals as deep as you want.

Like this:

```
library(libr)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Year    Firm    sales   wages
2014    A        12      4   
2015    A        8       3
2016    A        0       0 
2017    A        NA      NA 
2018    A        NA      NA 

2014    B        NA      NA   
2015    B        8       3
2016    B        4       2 
2017    B        9       5 
2018    B        8       6 

2014    C        9       5   
2015    C        7       6
2016    C        0       0 
2017    C        0       0
2018    C        0       0

2014    D        9       5   
2015    D        7       6
2016    D        8       0 
2017    D        0       4
2018    D        NA      NA')

df2 <- datastep(df, by = "Firm",
                retain = list(Closure_Sales = 0, 
                              Closure_Wages = 0, 
                              Closure_Both = 0),
                {
                  
                  # Reset to zero at start of group
                  if (first.) {
                    Closure_Sales <- 0 
                    Closure_Wages <- 0
                    Closure_Both <- 0
                  }
                  
                  # Increment once it gets to 1
                  if (Closure_Sales >= 1)
                    Closure_Sales <- Closure_Sales + 1
                  
                  if (Closure_Wages >= 1)
                    Closure_Wages <- Closure_Wages + 1
                  
                  if (Closure_Both >= 1)
                    Closure_Both <- Closure_Both + 1
                  
                  # Begin counting sales
                  if (!is.na(sales)) {
                    if (sales == 0) {
                      if (Closure_Sales == 0)
                        Closure_Sales <- 1
                      if (Closure_Both == 0)
                        Closure_Both <- 1
                    }
                  }
                  
                  # Begin counting wages
                  if (!is.na(wages)) {
                    if (wages == 0) {
                      if (Closure_Wages == 0)
                        Closure_Wages <- 1
                      if (Closure_Both == 0)
                        Closure_Both <- 1
                    }
                  }
                  
                })

# View results
df2
#    Year Firm sales wages Closure_Sales Closure_Wages Closure_Both
# 1  2014    A    12     4             0             0            0
# 2  2015    A     8     3             0             0            0
# 3  2016    A     0     0             1             1            1
# 4  2017    A    NA    NA             2             2            2
# 5  2018    A    NA    NA             3             3            3
# 6  2014    B    NA    NA             0             0            0
# 7  2015    B     8     3             0             0            0
# 8  2016    B     4     2             0             0            0
# 9  2017    B     9     5             0             0            0
# 10 2018    B     8     6             0             0            0
# 11 2014    C     9     5             0             0            0
# 12 2015    C     7     6             0             0            0
# 13 2016    C     0     0             1             1            1
# 14 2017    C     0     0             2             2            2
# 15 2018    C     0     0             3             3            3
# 16 2014    D     9     5             0             0            0
# 17 2015    D     7     6             0             0            0
# 18 2016    D     8     0             0             1            1
# 19 2017    D     0     4             1             2            2
# 20 2018    D    NA    NA             2             3            3
```

The `by` parameter activates the automatic variable `first.`, which identifies the start of the by group.  The `retain` parameter allows you to access the value of the previous row.   Inside the `datastep` you can access variable names directly.